# Java Linux cron scheduler for Spring web services (REST) - Method with arguments

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-mvc, cron

I need to define a scheduler for my Spring web services. I did the task using Quartz jobs. Actually, I will try to do it using Linux crons. The problem here is with methods with arguments since @Scheduled is not valid for methods with arguments:

```
//An example of a valid web method using @Scheduled:
@Scheduled
void exampleWebMethod(){

}
```

How can I apply Linux crons to  my  Spring web method which contains many arguments ?

Comment: What mechanism would you expect to pass in those required method arguments? You can't call a standalone Java method directly from the OS.

Comment: @kryger :I will pass some values like(String val, long userID)

Comment: What do you mean by "Linux crons"? Do you want do define a call to your webapp endpoint in the crontab? You don't need Spring for that. And if you want to keep the mechanism internal to your application you have to answer yourself one question: *why* `@Scheduled` can be only applied to no-arg methods? You can be sure it's not Spring developers' laziness.

Comment: Yes, I want to do that. I want to call web methods and associate  them with a linux cron (every x seconds call web method a of web service b). Anyway, when I did my search they said that @Scheduled is used with methods without arguments only. I tried "Quartz"  and it worked but wanna compare and see whether Linux crons will do better in terms of performance and efficiency.